# How to set Author Name, Added Time in MS Word Add-Ins Using Office.JS?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have developed Custom Add-ins in MS Word for adding Comments from TextArea.

Code is displayed below:

```
function myComment(some) {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var selectedText = some;
        let range = context.document.getSelection();
        var text = $("#areaDiv").val();
        var commentMessage = $.trim(text);
        if (selectedText != null && selectedText != "" && commentMessage != null && commentMessage != "") {
            $('#errorDiv').text('');
            var document = context.document;
            document.properties.load("author");
            context.sync().then(function () {
                var authorName = document.properties.author;
                $('#txtSearch').val(authorName);
            });
            var Initials = authorName;
            var matches = Initials.match(/\b(\w)/g);
            Initials = matches.join(''));
            range.insertOoxml(
                '<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"><pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512" ><pkg:xmlData ><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships" ><Relationship Id="rId1" Type = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData ></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/comments" Target="comments.xml" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:body><w:p><w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/><w:r><w:t>' + selectedText + '</w:t></w:r><w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/><w:r><w:commentReference w:id="0"/></w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage" pkg:name="/word/comments.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.comments+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:comments xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:comment xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:id="0"><w:p><w:r><w:t>' + commentMessage + '</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:comment></w:comments></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/comments.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part></pkg:package>',
                //'<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"><pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512" ><pkg:xmlData ><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships" ><Relationship Id="rId1" Type = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData ></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/comments" Target="comments.xml" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:body><w:p><w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/><w:r><w:t>' + selectedText + '</w:t></w:r><w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/><w:r><w:commentReference w:id="0"/></w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage" pkg:name="/word/comments.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.comments+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:comments xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:comment xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:id="0"><w:p><w:r><w:t>' + commentMessage + '</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:comment w:id="0" w:author=' + authorName + ' w:initials=' + returnInitials(authorName) + ' w:date=' + new Date() + '></w:comments></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/comments.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part></pkg:package>',
                "Replace"
            );
            $("#areaDiv").val('');
        }
        else {
            $('#errorDiv').text('Please enter and select text.');
        }
        return context.sync();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        $('#errorDiv').text(error);
    });
}
```

The current output and needed output are displayed in the below image. If I change anything in XML then its comments won't show over there.
If anyone have idea about the insertOoxml please revert me and also I have try with another way mentioned in comment.

[image: Let me know in case any findings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace your xml with below code.

```
'<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"><pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512" ><pkg:xmlData ><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships" ><Relationship Id="rId1" Type = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData ></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/comments" Target="comments.xml" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:body><w:p><w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/><w:r><w:t>' + selectedText + '</w:t></w:r><w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/><w:r><w:commentReference w:id="0"/></w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage" pkg:name="/word/comments.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.comments+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:comments xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:comment xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:id="0" w:author="' + author + '" w:date="' + str + '"><w:sdtContent><w:p><w:r><w:t>' + commentMessage + '</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:sdtContent></w:comment></w:comments></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/comments.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part></pkg:package>',
```

and it works fine.